# boostrap on wp-admin backend via plugin installation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

how can i add and use the twitter bootstrap to my wp-admin backend by a plugin installation approach?

i plan to create multiple custom plugins and i just want to add bootstrap as a global style instead of using it per plugin

this is my code, it doesnt seem to work.

```
<?php

/*
 * Plugin Name: bootstrap
 * Plugin URI: http://#/
 * Description: add boostrap
 * Author: some guy
 * Author URI: http://#/
 * Version: 0.1.0
 */


function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/custom/css/bootstrap.css');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use in the admin, you need the admin_enqueue_scripts hook instead of wp_enqueue_scripts.